# How to write character to an array of pointers in C?

Tags: c, char

Hello this might be asked before, but I couldn't find an answer to my problem.

```
for (int i = 0; i < StrLenght - 1; i++) {       
    if (szPattern[i] == '%') {
        // DO stuff....
    } else {
        szBuffer[i] = szPattern[i];
    }
}
```

So, before the **if** statement everything seems to be alright, I mean *szPattern* is correctly written to *szBuffer*, but once I go into the **if** statement nothing is written in the *szBuffer*....
I suspect it is because of the null terminated string "\0"..
Any idea how I can solve this problem??
Thanks.. :)

Comment: For the code you posted to work, `szPattern` would have to be an array of `char`.

Comment: Yes Robert, both szBuffer and szPattern are array of char

Comment: `C` tag is not appropriate for `C++` code

Comment: Indeed, sorry about that,

Comment: Not enough code. But I do wonder if szBuffer[] and szPattern have different lengths... if the '%' code picks up another character following the %,like sprintf() formats do, your incoming i and outgoing i become out of sync.  In such case  you would need a 'b' buffer and 'p' Pattern variable that increment as appropriate.;

Comment: @Metio_1993 Are you sure this is c++ code?

Comment: Can you tell the difference?

Comment: Because the question originally had `cout ` statement.  Anyway, the code as posted isn't a complete example of a program in either langauage.  I guess if you can't actually compile or run it, it's just pseudo code whatever it looks like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

1. A separate index for writing to `szBuffer`
2. Code that adds a zero termination to `szBuffer`

Like:

```
int j = 0;  // Index for storing in szBuffer
for (int i = 0; i < StrLenght - 1; i++) {       
    if (szPattern[i] == '%') {
        // DO stuff....
    } else {
        szBuffer[j] = szPattern[i]; // Assign using index j
        ++j;                        // Increment index
    }
}
szBuffer[j]  = '\0';  // Zero terminate 
puts(szBuffer);
```

Comment: This is working, can you explain why actually?

Comment: @Metio_1993 When you used `i` as index for writing to `szBuffer`, you got "holes" in the string when `szPattern` contained a '%'. To avoid that you need a separate index (j) that only increments when you actually assign to `szBuffer`